# Backbone | Array in model and manipulation

Tags: json, templates, backbone.js

I have a model like task(it has default properties like title, time, notes etc), and a collection like task list. Now there can be multiple notes on a single task. I have REST api (JSON) to populate model and collection. I need to list all the tasks(which is easy, ignoring  notes) and then view a task(including notes).

From here it seems to implement nested loops like thing in Backbone. How can I populate my model and show the task with all the notes. I am supposed to cover Model, Collection, View and template.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume in a pure RESTFUL implementation you have models `Task`, `Note` and collections `TaskList`, `TaskNotes`.

Initially you only want the Tasks to be loaded from the server, so you go `tasklist.fetch()`

This would expect all tasks to be synced with server but yet no task model in the collection contain any notes.

When user selects a task, you create a new `TaskNotes` instance, store it in parent task model (not as an attribute, because all attributes are passed to server by Backbone when saving) and fetch that.

That should be easy?

---

The real issue is that in case you want everything (all tasks, all their nested notes) to be fetched and initialized on a single call. That's a bit tricky because backbone doesn't deal with nested collections/models. All properties in JSON returned from server are considered as plain attributes. You'll need to look into something like [backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) or overriding [Model.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292667/populating-nested-collections-with-parent-model-fetch) method.

Saying that it's rare you want to fetch everything in a single call. That's too much data and users don't see all that data at once. It's better to do it on on-demand basis i.e. user selects task, you fetch notes.

Comment: Thanks nEEbz, Actually this was the thing I was thinking of but I am not able to figure out how to implement it. I mean I will need two different view (one for notes and one for rest of the details of task) and how to combine them. Combining them may be not an issue but a user can add another note on the task. Then how can I put the detail that with which task the newly added note linked to.

Comment: you'll need to store references of parent view. Just like how your `Note` model has reference (or id) to the parent `Task`. Similarly your `AddNote` view will have reference to the parent task as well. When user adds a note, you will add it to the parent task.