# Overriding parse in Backbone Collection, can't render results

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

After looking at a previous answer ref: [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292667/populating-nested-collections-with-parent-model-fetch), I'm looking to override parse so that I can pull out a nested collection of items, and use some other properties from my json response.

If I only have the items in my json It works without overriding parse. If I attempt to override parse then I don't see my items render, they are there in the data though.

This is an old project but I really need help figuring this out...

```
var ContentListingBlock = ViewController.extend({
        name: 'module/content-listing-block/view/main-view-controller',
        template: templates['module/content-listing-block/main-view-controller'],
        expectedRegions: ['items-region'],

        contents: '',
        json: '',

        onStart: function() {
            console.log('ContentListingBlock')
            var $this = this;

            var Item = Backbone.Model.extend()
            $this.ItemCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Item
            })

            var ContentListing = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/data',
                parse: function(response) {
                    response.items = new $this.ItemCollection(response.items)
                    return response
                }
            });

            $this.contents = new ContentListing()

            $this.showResults()

            $('.button-fetch').on('click', function(){
                $this.fetchItems()
            })

        },

        fetchItems: function() {
            var $this = this

            this.contents.fetch({
                data: { page: 1, size: 6 },
                processData: true
            }).then(function(){
               console.log('data:', $this.contents)
            })
        },

        showResults: function() {
            var $this = this

            var ItemCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
                tagName: 'section',
                childView: ItemView
            })

            this['items-region'].show(new ItemCollectionView({ collection: $this.contents.items }))
        }
    })

    return ContentListingBlock
```

and here is my model

```
{
    "data": {
        "pageSize": 6,
        "pagesNum": 3,
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "imagePath": "image.jpg",
                "categoryType": "A",
                "storyTitle": "Story Title 2",
                "content": "Story content...",
                "quoteFlag": "false",
                "author": "Paul Dirac"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "imagePath": "image.jpg",
                "categoryType": "B",
                "storyTitle": "Story Title 3",
                "content": "Story content...",
                "quoteFlag": "false",
                "author": "Nikola Tesla"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "imagePath": "image.jpg",
                "categoryType": "B",
                "storyTitle": "Story Title 4",
                "content": "Story content...",
                "quoteFlag": "false",
                "author": "Max Planck"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your view rendering after the fetch? Render seems to have happened before the event handler was even bound?

Comment: OK in backbone marionette it will render fine after fetch, this all works great if I only have a json structure with items. As soon as I nest the items in a further object, I need to parse it according to other answers, this issue is how to get the marionette view and collection bound together

Comment: The collection updates after a fetch and is being watched

Comment: You need to call render explicitly